# Como assegurar que um código em um Cortex-A esteja executando com a frequência máxima da CPU

Tags: linux, cortex-a, clock, cpu

Ao executar um código em C eu preciso executar a cada 30ms um conjunto de calculos que transforma uma imagem e que está levando até 100ms o que me obriga a descartar 3 de cada 4 frames que obtenho.

Como posso garantir que a frequência do clock da CPU está ao máximo?

Estou usando um Cortex-A53 que roda entre 400Mhz a 1400Mhz.

Abaixo está o resultado do comando `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

```
Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
processor       : 0
BogoMIPS        : 1594.36

processor       : 1
BogoMIPS        : 1594.36

processor       : 2
BogoMIPS        : 1594.36

processor       : 3
BogoMIPS        : 1594.36

processor       : 4
BogoMIPS        : 1601.53

processor       : 5
BogoMIPS        : 1594.36

processor       : 6
BogoMIPS        : 1594.36

processor       : 7
BogoMIPS        : 1594.36
```

Cheguei a tentar usar o código sugerido neste link para saber qual a velocidade do processador, mas não estou conseguindo compila-lo pois não acho os includes corretos:

https://superuser.com/questions/406141/how-to-get-an-arm-cpu-clock-speed-in-linux

Qual seria o código correto para obter a frequência atual do clock da CPU e como ajustar em tempo de execução para que use o máximo?

Estou usando o Linux, com C++ no GCC 4.9, em um Cortex-A53.

Comment: Pode não parecer mas a pergunta tem a ver com programação.

Comment: Olá @bigown, eu preciso fazer algum ajuste?

Comment: A título de informação consegui fazer manualmente ajustes usando a ferramenta cpufreq-set mudando a estratégia de manutenção da frequência para "performance", mas mesmo assim o que desejo é que meu próprio código seja capaz de solicitar a máxima performance do processador.

Comment: A pergunta não está nota 10, mas acho que dá para responder. O problema de terem votado para fechar é que a pessoa lê "processador" e acha que é hardware :) Mas está claro que não é.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, vou tentar melhora-la.
Qualquer ajuste é bem vindo.